# Blank pages when running the ZendFramework 2 skeleton application

Tags: php, zend-framework, skeleton-code

I am trying to run the ZendFramework 2 [skeleton](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app) application locally. I am new to this framework.

After creating a PHP5 application on Openshift using instructions available [here](https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache), I cloned it locally and unzipped the Zend Skeleton application into it. I had Composer install dependencies via Netbeans.

As mentioned in the Zend instructions, I went to my `public` directory and started the built-in server:

```
cd public
php -S localhost:8888
```

When I open `http://localhost:8888/` or `http://localhost:8888/public`, I get a blank page. When I open `http://localhost:8888/public/index.php`, I get a nice page with an error message:

```
The requested resource /public/index.php was not found on this server.
```

It is surely some configuration issue, but I don't know which. Anyone knows what is happening?

Comment: Only guessing, but it would appear you are running the server from within the `public` directory. I'm assuming that you don't have a `public/public` directory and so `http://localhost:8888/public` won't exist. `http://localhost:8888` will be the index page from the public folder. As for the blank page, check your error logs. You likely have display_errors turned off and so it throws a 500 error instead of displaying the error.

Comment: I was confused by the fact that http://localhost:8888 returned a blank page. In fact, the index.php does not display anything. I added a print and something was displayed. Thanks.

Comment: Jonathan, if you create an answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only guessing, but it would appear you are running the server from within the `public` directory. I'm assuming that you don't have a `public/public` directory and so `http://localhost:8888/public` won't exist. `http://localhost:8888` will be the index page from the public folder. As for the blank page, check your error logs. You likely have display_errors turned off and so it throws a 500 error instead of displaying the error.